# Vertica: split string to array and group over to get set of unique values?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a column on Vertica which stores numbers as a string of values concatenated by commas, for example: `12,15,17`, for example:

```
ID  |  values
----------------------
A   | 1,3,5
A   | 2,3,5,6
B   | 1,2,3
```

I'd like to get this as my end result:

```
ID  |  values
----------------------
A   | 1,2,3,5,6
B   | 1,2,3
```

meaning, for each ID a s et of all different values. How do I do this?
(Using Vertica 8.1.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
Assuming you know what is the max number of values per entry (let's assume 6 in this example):

```
with m as (
  select 1 as i union all
  select 2 as i union all
  select 3 as i union all
  select 4 as i union all
  select 5 as i union all
  select 6 as i),
splitted_data as (
  select distinct ID, split_part('values',',',i) as value
  from main_table cross join m)
select ID, rtrim(agg_concatenate(value||','),',') as values
from splitted_data
```